# How to make hero area fill the entire browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am just wondering how to achieve this effect:

**https://www.udemy.com/**

The Hero area of the website takes up the full width of the browser even though the browser window is resized.

I will really appreciate if you can let me see how this done from the markup to jQuery.

Comment: And I would really appreciate if you could provide me some code, what have you tried? or do you expect me to do it for you..

Comment: What do you mean by hero area?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about (I assume from your link) `background-size:cover`.

You can achieve this with no jQuery, just CSS and HTML, using:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

A full tutorial can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).